# Calculating velocity for Cannonball trajectory in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, velocity, angle

My objective is to create a cannonball type effect for a projectile. Basically, when you click a coordinate, the cannonball will launch and land at that specific coordinate. I know well how to create a projectile that will travel directly (in a straight line) to said coordinate, however because I want it to have a realistic looking cannonball trajectory I am having trouble. I am able to get pretty close but it's always off by a bit in either direction and im not sure what im doing wrong. I should mention that the starting coordinate of the projectile x and y are not fixed, and the desired coordinate x and y of where the projectile needs to end are also not fixed.

```
var gravity:Number = .25;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, promov);
function promov(event:Event):void
{ 
  if (ingame)
  {
    if (firepressed)   
    { proj.yVel = 0;
      pos = new Point(coor.x, coor.y);
      projpos = new Point(proj.x, proj.y);
      proj.angle = Math.atan2(proj.x-coor.x, proj.y-coor.y);
      proj.xVel = (proj.angle-Math.PI*Math.abs(proj.angle)/proj.angle)*Point.distance(projpos, pos)/30;
      firepressed = false; }
      
    if (proj.shot) 
    { proj.y+=proj.yVel;
      proj.yVel+=gravity;
      proj.x+=proj.xVel; }
  }
}
```

the "proj.xVel = " line is the equation I have there now, however obviously I know it's wrong. I've done some google searching for the right equation but can't seem to find anything. If there are any math people who also know AS3 out there please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: A cannonball (we assume gravity and no air friction) moves along the parabolic curve with the formula **y = ax^2 + bx + c**, where **a** is negative and depends both on gravity constant G and projectile velocity (I cannot say how, though). You know start point **(x1,y1)** and end point **(x2,y2)** of this curve, you should figure **a**, **b** and **c**. The launch angle would be a derivative of the curve in **(x1,y1)**, i.e. **2ax1 + b**.

Comment: You have a mathematical task. Having a cannon at (x0,y0) you need to hit (x1,y1) with a projectile in a gravity field of strength "g", for this you need to calculate (vx, vy). This task has an infinite number of solutions, probably you need to set up another constraint (total speed or vx\*vx+vy\*vy, angle aka vy/vx as examples), with a constraint you'll get 2 or 0 solutions, depending on input data. This is solvable analytically

Comment: Regarding that your actual projectile is missing, the core problem here is that you treat `proj.x` as a true float, while this is actually truncated at set to match 1/20 of a pixel (forgot how is this named, a "pip" or something). To fix, use `realX` and `realY` on a projectile and store doubles in there, use them for floating point calculations and assign x and y after a frame's worth of movement to avoid error accumulation.

Comment: @Vesper It's *twixel*, like *one twentieth of a pixel*.